# OutOfMemoryException while receveing data from server

Tags: android, json

We are preparing a server client application in Android, and we are facing problem in receiving data from my server.

Application is throwing **Out Of Memory Exception**`(Out of memory on a 57283558-byte allocation.)` Although I have specified `largeHeap=true` Attribute in my `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: is images involved in ur application?

Comment: No I am just getting data from the server and throws Exception

Comment: ok , go for lazy loading[which can fetch ur data in background and cache it]

Comment: You should load less data at once. That seems to be too much for your android device. Or you should check if you leak memory.

Comment: are you running this on the emulator ?? then increase the vm heap size, and yes 60mb data is huge, you need to send in the data in a way such that you can fetch it and store in the sqlite db.

Comment: When I Write Json Response in text file the size of text file is 30 mb...

Comment: @DharaShah I am Running On My Device (Tablet)...

Comment: you will have to use a streaming api as mentioned in one of the answers below. It is not possible to receive all the data at once, since if i am not wrong that will be stored in the cache or ram when received, and it would definitely cause an OOM exception. There is n shortcut to this. If you try reading it from the file also, there is one point in time this exception will be raised. we faced a similar issue, and what we could do is change the way the service returns the data.

Answer (score 0):

A 60Mb json response seems excessive.  If that's actually what you're expecting, then you might need to look at a different type of response, or on the fly parsing. Hard to say without more detail...

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you are trying to save what you are downloading, in memory and that's why you get the OOM.

You can take a look at [DownloadManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.html) if you are API 9 and above

or try something in the lines of:

```java
URL url = new URL("http://www.example.com/largefile.zip");
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
FileOutputStream out = openFileOutput("largefile.zip", Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Edit:
I caught a glimpse of a mention for an 60mb json response. You should really reconsider what you are doing. Perhaps you could use [Jackson Streaming API](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonStreamingApi) to parse and save the response in db or something you can use later on